# joomla ckeditor link browser alert object XMLHttpRequest

Tags: browser, joomla, hyperlink, ckeditor, alert

I am using CKEditor in a Joomla 3 installation and the Link Browser tab is not working. I have installed the CKFinder plugin for it as well. No matter what option is selected in the tree, it only displays an alert box that says [object XMLHttpRequest] and nothing else happens. Am I missing something or does this feature just not work?

Comment: It might be some integration issue. You may take a look on [file upload demo](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html) to see how it works. Also take a look an [upload file integration guides](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_browse_upload.html), maybe it may help.